# Measure memory consumption with all HttpSessions in Tomcat at an arbitrary point in time

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, profiler, httpsession

I want to measure the percentage of memory used by `HttpSession` in a web application.

Is there any way to measure memory consumption with all `HttpSession`s in a running Tomcat instance at an arbitrary point in time without modifying the application?

### What I have tried

- In Tomcat, the concrete class of `HttpSession` is `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession`. I have profiled the application with VisualVM and specified `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession` in `[Profiler]-[Memory settings]`. But it shows only the size of `StandardSession` itself (the size of `ConcurrentHashMap` contained in `StandardSession` is not included).
- I have profiled the application with Flight Recorder and viewed the result with Mission Control. But I cannot find out which objects are referenced from `HttpSession`.
- [You can list all HttpSession with `org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase#findSessions()` and measure the size of `HttpSession`s with Byteman and `SizeOf.deepSizeOf()`](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/165472). But this Byteman rule runs only when a new `HttpSession` is created. I want measure memory consumption with `HttpSession`s at an arbitrary point in time (e.g. in every 30 seconds).

Comment: Interesting question. May be with [verbose GC logs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-logging-to-file) but it's a long shot. If it were possible to modify the application, perhaps JMX could be a good option.

Comment: @LMC Thank you for your comment. I made a sample project to get the size of HttpSession with JMX: https://github.com/satob/SessionSize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comment from @LMC, I made a sample project to get the size of HttpSession with JMX: https://github.com/satob/SessionSize

Note that because you cannot access `org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase` directly, this project uses [ByteMan](https://byteman.jboss.org/). Store the `ManagerBase` object to a static field of the MBean `SessionMonitor` with Byteman like:

```
RULE Set ManagerBase object to MBean
CLASS ^org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase
METHOD initInternal
AT EXIT
IF TRUE
DO
    traceln("SETTING SessionManager");
    com.example.sessionsize.SessionMonitor.setSessionManager($this);
ENDRULE
```

and use it in the JMX interface like:

```java
package com.example.sessionsize;

import org.apache.catalina.Manager;
import org.apache.catalina.Session;

import net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf;

public class SessionMonitor implements SessionMonitorMBean {

    private static Manager sessionManager = null;

    public static void setSessionManager(Manager manager) {
        sessionManager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public long getMemoryConsumption() {
        if (sessionManager != null) {
            try {
                Session [] sessions = sessionManager.findSessions();
                return SizeOf.deepSizeOf(sessions);
            } catch(RuntimeException e) {
                // Falied to get size of HttpSession object
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -2;
            }
        } else {
            // SessionManager is not ready
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getNumberOfActiveHttpSession() {
        return sessionManager.findSessions().length;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! Just curious, what's the size of a httpSession compared to the plain size of 100000 UUID objects? (+- 100kb if end of lines are included)

Comment: @LMC Added a screenshot to the answer. The size of a large string (concatinated 100,000 UUIDs) on HttpSession was about 7.3MB. Note that the size of 100,000 UUID strings on HttpSession was about 26.7MB.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like there's a significant overhead on building the session object.